# What was the symbolism/purpose of the play in Entebbe (2018)?

Tags: plot-explanation, entebbe, 7-days-in-entebbe

In Entebbe (2018), we see play being praticised and then being performed during the assault on Entebbe.

What was the purpose of the scene, was there a direct connection, was someone in the crowd watching from the assault?

The clip below is incase anyway what to know what dance was performed if they hadn't seen it.

Comment: It's not a play, it is a dance.

Answer (score 0):

[According to CinemaBlend](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2388561/why-7-days-in-entebbe-includes-a-dance-number-according-to-daniel-bruhl):

> I recently spoke with actor **Daniel Bruhl** (*Captain America: Civil War*, *Inglorious Basterds*) who stars as terrorist Wilfried Böse. When asked about the dance, Bruhl spoke to what it represented in the film.
>
> > **To show the pain and processing -- everything that conflict involves.** Not only by telling the military mission; we've seen a lot of shoot outs and raids in film history. They thought this was not enough, and they were combining it with that highly emotional dance. That gives a lot of possibility for interpretation, and a very thought provoking moment in the film. So I like it a lot.